# kubectl- The connection to the server x.x.x.:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-apiserver

I have set up a kubernetes cluster with a master node and a worker node. I am facing below error whenever I run a kubectl command-

```
The connection to the server x.x.x.:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port? Kubernetes
```

To resolve this- I have followed below steps:

1. sudo -i
2. swapoff -a
3. exit
4. strace -eopenat kubectl version

But this solution resolves the error only for sometime ( temporary solution ), after few minutes I get the same error. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting services as they may have gone stale.

- sudo systemctl restart kubelet
- sudo systemctl restart kube-apiserver
- sudo systemctl restart kube-scheduler
- sudo systemctl restart kube-controller-manager

Also check if there are any firewall rules that may be blocking port 6443. If all else fails, you may need to restart the master node. Attached is a good read for kubernetes networking that may help your use case.[1]

[1]

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/